# jQuery .animate looped sequence

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I'm attempting to create a looped sequence that displays frames one after another.

I have used jQuery .animate to create this e.g.

```
$frame1.delay(0).animate({opacity: 1}, 0);
$frame1.delay(100).animate({opacity: 0}, 0);
```

and that seems to work once. However when I loop the sequence the frames start to jump around in the wrong order.

Is anyone able to see what is happening here and where I have gone wrong?

[See jsfiddle for full sequence](https://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/waudhsnm/)

Comment: if you use an animation duration of 0, have you tried changing the css directly? .css("opacity",0) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable set to `0` which increments within single recursive function to animate each `.frame` element using `$.when()` , `.then()` , `.eq()` , `.fadeTo()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  function walk(el, n) {
    // `el` : `$(".frame")` elements
    return $.when(
        el.eq(n).fadeTo(500, 1)
      ).then(function() {
        return this.fadeTo(500, 0)
      })
      .then(function() {
        // if `n` less than `$(".frame")` `.length` ,
        // call `walk`, else return `$(".frame")` : `el` elements
        return ++n < el.length ? walk(el, n) : el
      })
  };
  // pass `$(".frame")` , `0` to `walk`
  walk($(".frame"), 0).then(function() {
    // `this` : `.frame` elements
    console.log(this)
    alert("complete")
  });
  
});
```

```css
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="frame1" class="frame">1</div>
<div id="frame2" class="frame">2</div>
<div id="frame3" class="frame">3</div>
<div id="frame4" class="frame">4</div>
<div id="frame5" class="frame">5</div>
<div id="frame6" class="frame">6</div>
<div id="frame7" class="frame">7</div>
<div id="frame8" class="frame">8</div>
<div id="frame9" class="frame">9</div>
<div id="frame10" class="frame">10</div>
<div id="frame11" class="frame">11</div>
<div id="frame12" class="frame">12</div>
```